# Iterating trough rows and getting the current and only next row if a condition is met python

Tags: python

```js
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2022-06-01', '2022-06-02', '2022-06-04', '2022-06-08'], 'sent':['true', 'true', 'false', 'true']})

         date   sent
0  2022-06-01   true
1  2022-06-02   true
2  2022-06-04  false
3  2022-06-08   true
4  2022-06-09   true
5  2022-06-10  false
6  2022-06-12   true
7  2022-06-14   true
```

i want to iterate trough this df and when sent == 'false' i want to save this and only the next following rows in a new df.

so i want two have a second df like this

```js
         date   sent
2  2022-06-04  false
3  2022-06-08   true
5  2022-06-10  false
6  2022-06-12   true
```

Comment: `idx = df_test[df_test['sent'] == 'false'].index[0]; print(df_test.iloc[idx:idx+2])` assuming you only want the first false and next value. If you want all false and next values please update your question and sample data. If you want all rows after the first false value then `df_test.iloc[df_test[df_test['sent'] == 'false'].index[0]:]`

Comment: just edited the sample

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sent_false = (df_test['sent'] == 'false')

df_sent_false = df_test[sent_false | sent_false.shift(1)]
print(df_sent_false)

         date   sent
2  2022-06-04  false
3  2022-06-08   true
```

With resetting the index:

```
df_sent_false.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

         date   sent
0  2022-06-04  false
1  2022-06-08   true
```